# I am getting an error message that password does not match in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a "UsercreationForm" in django.
When I saved the form, it didn't create any entry in database then I debug it and found an error message that **Password fields does not match**
I don't know what I did wrong. Please help me figure it out.

**Here is my forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from accounts.models import Customer, User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from datetime import datetime

class UserSignup(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","first_name", "last_name", "email")
        
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", required=True)
    first_name= forms.CharField(label="First Name", required=True)
    last_name=forms.CharField(label="Last Name", required=False)
    email =forms.EmailField(label="Email", required=False)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", required=True)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", required=True)

    def username_clean(self):  
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()  
        new = User.objects.filter(username = username)  
        if new.count():  
            raise ValidationError("User Already Exist")  
        return username  
  
    def email_clean(self):  
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()  
        new = User.objects.filter(email=email)  
        if new.count():  
            raise ValidationError(" Email Already Exist")  
        return email  
  
    def clean_password2(self):  
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']  
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']  
  
        if password1 != password2:  
            raise ValidationError("Password don't match")  
        return password2  
  
    def save(self, commit = True):  
        user = User.objects.create_user(  
            self.cleaned_data['username'],  
            self.cleaned_data['email'],  
            self.cleaned_data['password1'],
            last_login= datetime.now()
        )  
        return user  
    
class AddDetails(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ("age", "phone")
        
    age = forms.IntegerField(label="Age", required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(label="Mobile Number", required=True)
```

**Here is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from accounts.forms import *
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib import messages  

def usersignup(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        
        # User Sign-up form (username, email, first_name, last_name, password1, password2)
        user_form= UserSignup()
        
        # Customer detail form (age and phone number)
        details_form = AddDetails(request.POST)
        
        # If both forms are valid
        if all((user_form.is_valid(), details_form.is_valid())):
            # Saving with commit=False gets you a model object, then you can add your extra data and save it.
            user = user_form.save()
            customer= details_form.save(commit=False)
            # As user is in OnetoOne Relationship with customer
            customer.user= user
            customer.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')  
            # return redirect('details')
        
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    user_form =UserSignup()
    details_form= AddDetails()
    return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'details_form': details_form})
```

**Here is registration_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}  
  
{% block content %}  
  
<div class = "login">  
  
    {% if messages %}  
        <ul>   
            {% for message in messages %}  
                <li>{{ message }}</li>  
                {% endfor %}  
        </ul>   
    {% endif %}  
      
    <h1>Sign up for new account</h1>  
  
         <form method="post" >  
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
            {{user_form.as_table}}
            {{details_form.as_table}}
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></td>  
                </tr>  
             </table>  
         </form>  
     </div>  
  
{% endblock content %}
```

**Here are my models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Customer(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age= models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    phone= models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

Both passwords are matched. but still getting errors.

[image: My error message]

Comment: Not sure, but you are using `self.cleaned_data['password2'] ` in `clean_password2` method. I think at this point `password2` is not in cleaned_data yet

Comment: @Djangodev Does [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72169715/17562044) answer doesn't resolved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is because of your `if` condition in the `usersignup` view, try some modifications in it, for checking both form validation try changing it to `if user_form.is_valid() and details_form.is_valid():`, in the following way:

views.py

```py
def usersignup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # User Sign-up form (username, email, first_name, last_name, password1, password2)
        user_form = UserSignup(request.POST)

        # Customer detail form (age and phone number)
        details_form = AddDetails(request.POST)

        # If both forms are valid
        if user_form.is_valid() and details_form.is_valid():
            # Saving with commit=False gets you a model object, then you can add your extra data and save it.
            user = user_form.save()
            customer = details_form.save(commit=False)
            # As user is in OnetoOne Relationship with customer
            customer.user = user
            customer.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
            # return redirect('details')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    user_form = UserSignup()
    details_form = AddDetails()
    return render(request, 'home/registration_form.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'details_form': details_form})
```

> `Note:` Function based views are generally written in `snake_case` not in  `smallcase`, it will be better if you changed it to `user_sign_up` from `usersignup`.